# Error: "Automator could not access your calendars"

Tags: macos, mac, automator

How do i give access to automator?

I press "don't allow" by mistake the first time the calendar event try to open the action

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/calendar/index.html).

At System Preferences-> Security & Privacy, privacy tab select the Calendar and activate the checkbox for the action wanted.